# CodeIgniter: How to set a controller function to be a post route?

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I usually use something like:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function save() {
        if($this->input->is_post()) { //my own method
           ......
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way, eg. in Slim framework:

```
post("/user/save", function() {
    ......
});
```

or in .Net MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult save(User model) {
    ......
}
```

Or can CodeIgniter handle this in its route config file?
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter has no built-in support for REST. If you want it, you need to use third-party library or write your own. For third-party library, Here is good one : [codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) .

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Although for now this is the only answer, but the library works well and is enough for me. All I do then is creating MY_Controller extending REST_Controller from the library. Thanks.

Answer (score -6):

To remove `index.php` use this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```