# How can I insert data from an AngularJS form in a database using a CodeIgniter controller?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, post, routes

I have a project that's being made with CodeIgniter, we want to use PHP for the server and AngularJS for the client. I want too to insert the name and the ID of a User into our database
This is the AngularJS code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Angular Forms</title>

  <!-- LOAD BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- LOAD JQUERY -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- LOAD ANGULAR -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

 
  <script>
    // define angular module/app
    var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);
    // create angular controller and pass in $scope and $http
    function formController($scope, $http) {
      // create a blank object to hold our form information
      // $scope will allow this to pass between controller and view
      $scope.formData = {};
      // process the form
      $scope.processForm = function() {
        $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'http://localhost/alpha2/index.php/user/insert',
              data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
              headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
          })
              .success(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  if (!data.success) {
                    // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                      $scope.erroridAlumno = data.errors.idAlumno;
                      $scope.errorNombre = data.errors.nombre;
                  } else {
                    // if successful, bind success message to message
                      $scope.message = data.message;
                      $scope.erroridAlumno = '';
                      $scope.errorNombre = '';
                  }
              });
      };
    }
  </script>
        <style>
            .ng-valid.ng-dirty{
                border-color: green;
            }
            .ng-invalid.ng-dirty{
                border-color: red;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<!-- apply the module and controller to our body so angular is applied to that -->
<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

  <!-- PAGE TITLE -->
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span> Insertar Nuevo Alumno</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- SHOW ERROR/SUCCESS MESSAGES -->
  <div id="messages" class="well" ng-show="message">{{ message }}</div>

  <!-- FORM -->
  <form ng-submit="processForm()">
    <!-- ID -->
    <div id="idAlumno-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : erroridAlumno }">
      <label>ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="idAlumno" class="form-control" placeholder="Bruce Wayne" ng-model="formData.idAlumno">
                        <span class="help-block" ng-show="erroridAlummno">{{ erroridAlumno }}</span>
    </div>

    <!-- NAME -->
    <div id="nombre-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorNombre }">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Caped Crusader" ng-model="formData.nombre">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorNombre">{{ errorNombre }}</span>
    </div>

   

    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
    </button>
  </form>

  <!-- SHOW DATA FROM INPUTS AS THEY ARE BEING TYPED -->
  <pre>
    {{ formData }}
  </pre>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my PHP project, I have a controller (and a model) named "User".
This controller has three methods: Index, Users, and Insert.
Insert is the method I'm trying to make it work, the one I use to insert new data into the database.

I think it may be a problem with routes.php (at the config folder), I don't know what to put there.

What would be the correct code at User/insert to insert the data into the database?
What would be the correct code for routes.php to make it work?

The model of the User entity is named "user_model".
This is the code of the model:

```html
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {



        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }

  public function get_users($id = FALSE)
  {
          if ($id === FALSE)
          {
                  $query = $this->db->get('alumno');
                  return $query->result_array();
          }

          $query = $this->db->get_where('alumno', array('idAlumno' => $id));
          return $query->row_array();
  }

  public function insert_user($data){
   
        $query = $this->db->insert('alumno',$data);
        return $query;
    }

  


}


?>
```

("alumno" is the name of the table in my database)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: First of all you have to make sure that your server side controller accept POST request. So write code for routes.php and controller side accordingly. Get data posted from angular using the request object or $_POST...i think thats all you need to write more

Comment: The method to get posted data at codeigniter is "$this->input->post('nameOfTheVariable')". But I don't know how to write proper code in routes.php and the controller.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159612/codeigniter-how-to-set-a-controller-function-to-be-a-post-route or directly REST endpoints with codeigniter https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: I was (am) already using the codeigniter-restserver so it can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using **codeigniter-restserver** then you need to have method name accordingly to support different methods of **HTTP request**.

**For example :**
If you're making an HTTP GET call to `/books`, for instance, it would call a `Books#index_get()` method.

**Similarly**, in your case your method name must be **`insert_post()`** in your controller to support your POST request from **Angular AJAX POST**.

So, in your User Controller there must be a method `insert_post()` to support the url `...../user/insert`

See Handling HTTP Request [Handling Request](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#handling-requests)